# First row of Google-Sheet is not being considered in JavaScript Loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to send an automatic email on a reoccurring basis. My Google-App-script is working fine with the exception that it does not email the 1st email, i.e. first row. It starts the looping process of emails from the second row on. How do I tweak this issue in my code?

```
function sendemail() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var secondSheet = spreadSheet[1];
  var dataRange = secondSheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

 
     for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { 
        (function(val) {
          var row = data[i];
          var emailAddress = row[0]; 
          var message = 'Test Email';
    
          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, message);
          })(i);
       }
    }
```

It only emails 'email2' and 'email3' but not to 'email1' in this case. How do I get it to send emails to all emails?

[image]

Comment: You need to start with `i = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for-loop should start with zero. When you start with 1, you skip the first email in the array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ... }
```

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

> JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed. The first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index value equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1.

[`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns an array, so you need to be careful to use the correct index. This is different from the range indexes used by Google, but is noted in the documentation.

> Remember that while a range index starts at 1, 1, the JavaScript array is indexed from [0][0].